# How to use FIND_IN_SET in sequelize with mysql DB

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

How to use the FIND_IN_SET in sequelize ORM or any equivalent in sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to drop back to a [raw query](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html). Most ORM systems don't handle MySQL functions terribly well.

As an example for the where query:

```
// This is *NOT* the best way to use FIND_IN_SET
sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(username, 'foo,bar,baz') < 3", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(users => {
      // only users with the name "foo" or "bar"
  })


// This is better, I guess.
sequelize.query("SELECT FIND_IN_SET(username, 'foo,bar,baz') as `idx`, id FROM `users`", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(value => {
      console.log(value.id + ' has an idx of ' + value.idx);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

An example for the `FIND_IN_SET` in sequelize row query:

```
sequelize.query("select * from student where id in (10,2,12,9) ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '10,2,12,9')", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT};
```

Sequelize Version: 
CLI: 3.2.0 
ORM: 4.10.3